# School assignment in C. Sort random numbers, not workning

Tags: c, sorting, random

I go web development in school and we learn the basics of C. What I share now is part of a larger task.
This part is; **make random numbers between 100-900**, **print them in a matrix 10x10 and then sort the numbers in the matrix**.

I get random numbers. And numbers are sorted. But not the right numbers. It sort completely new numbers why...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void slumptal(int slumpArray[]);
void printArray(int slumpArray[]);
void sortera(int sortArray[]);
void printsort(int sortArray[]);

/*Main, där programmet initieras */
int main(void)
{
    int array[100];
    srand(time(NULL)); //seed
    slumptal(array);
    printArray(array);
    sortera(array);
    printsort(array);
    return 0;
}

/* Funktion som slumpar tal och sparar i array..Random numbers stored in a array*/
void slumptal(int slumpArray[])
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        slumpArray[x] = rand() % 801 + 101;
    }
}

/*Funktion som skriver ut matrisen.. Print the matrix*/
void printArray(int slumpArray[])
{
    printf("\n");
    for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y < 10; y++)
        {
            printf("%4d", slumpArray[x * 10 + y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/*Funktion som sorterar elementen i matrisen. Sort element in the matrix */
void sortera(int sortArray[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
        for (int j = 100; j > i; j--)
            if (sortArray[j - 1] > sortArray[j])
            {
                int slask = sortArray[j - 1];
                sortArray[j - 1] = sortArray[j];
                sortArray[j] = slask;
            }
    
}

/*Funktion som skriver ut sorteringen. Print the sorted numbers */
void printsort(int sortArray[])
{
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
        printf("%4d", sortArray[i]);
    }
}
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWf3L.png)

Comment: Hi, please format your code :)

Comment: It does not work here. I printed it as it should be. but all text just went to the left. At least I managed to <br> the lines.

Comment: @Izypekka surround your code with triple backticks `.

Comment: In `printsort()` , you go out of bounds. Array indexes, in your case, range from `0-99`, not `0-100` .

Comment: Apart from that, codes seems to work fine for me. Maybe you should provide the output you're receiving and what you expected to receive.

Comment: Make the habit of writing all identifiers and comments in English. For the day when you need someone else to look at the code. Like... when posting it on SO, for example.

Comment: `sortArray[j - 1] > sortArray[j]` <- Bad idea when j=100

Comment: alex01011 - I added a picture "the output" link. the first numers (10x10) are the random numbers. Below them there´s sorted number. But not the same as those above.

Comment: The `x` and `y` loop counters in `printArray` should start at 0, not 1. The loop test condition in `printSort` should be `i < 100`, not `i < 101`. The outer loop test condition in `sortera` should be `i < 100`, not `i < 101`. The loop initial value in the inner loop of `sortera` should be `j = 99`, not `j = 100`.

Comment: Lundin - Thank you, I will consider that if i post more things

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think it works now. What I was thinking when I wrote 101 etc. Was that I might have confused it with index or something. Because it starts at zero and not one

Comment: Compile wih `-fsanitize=address` to discover obo-errors

Answer (score 0):

```
slumpArray[x] = rand() % 801 + 101;
```

output would be  101 <= x <= 901.

add 100 (and not 101) to get values  100 <= x <= 900

Comment: While this is true, it's not really the problem here